# Create a hash of references in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reference, copy

I have a hash with values being arrays.
The problem is that I  have groups of keys where the values of two keys in the groups have to be identical.

So I need to make sure that the hash is a hash of references not values, but am unsure of the copy semantics of ruby.

Comment: give us examples. what do you mean by `classes of keys`? what do you mean by `copy semantics of ruby.`?

Comment: please provide some sample inputs and outputs as an examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
a = %w(a b c) # create an array
p a # have a look at it
p a.object_id # this is how ruby references the array
# =>68669980
hash = {'a_key'=>a} #put it in a hash
p hash['a_key']# have a look at it again
p hash['a_key'].object_id # no copy, just a reference
# =>68669980
```

Comment: The important thing to note here is that everything is a reference in Ruby. Even `:foo` or `2` are just references to a singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question about "hash of references", regarding arrays:

```
   array = [1,2]
   hash = { :k1 => array, :k2 => array }
   hash[:k1].push(3)
   puts hash[:k2].inspect
   => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

As you can see, the array variable is a reference to the underlying object in Ruby. This is true for most objects in Ruby, except a few "immediate" types, such as `Fixnum` and `Float`.

So you can use Ruby as you need for your data structure with two hash keys pointing to the same object. Note this may not be preserved if you make a round trip though data serialisation, and it is not preserved if you assign a new object to one of the keys.

Relevant language semantics are:

1. Ruby variables are references to objects.
2. Assignment to a variable, array element or hash key does not copy the object, it stores a new reference in the variable.
3. Using an object as a parameter to a method does not create a copy, it passes a reference
4. Many of the methods on `Array`, `Hash` and `String` will create and return new objects. Some methods appear in two versions e.g. `map` and `map!`, where the former version returns a new object and the latter alters the object in place.
5. There are some exceptions: "immediate" objects that *are* copied on assignment and when passed to a method. This includes built-in numeric types.

Comment: I have not had a chance to check the second part, but the first part I meant a hash whose values are references not whose keys are references.

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog I do not mention keys as references in my answer - sorry if anything is badly worded or confusing. Any Ruby object can be used as a key to a hash, and all Ruby variables are references, but that is not "using a reference as a hash key". Instead, Ruby arranges if two objects are considered equal, they will have the same hash code generated. So Ruby will treat two *different* string objects with the same content `a="hello"` and `b="hello"` as identical hash keys, and will treat the *same* object with different content (at different times) as two different keys.